# Two player game for complete noobs

Tags: game-recommendation, one-on-one

I want to play some tabletop rpg with my SO. They have no experience in any games at all and I've been playing on PC all my life, also I played one session of DnD as a player (I don't know which edition).

Any setting would be ok except horror to try.

Idealy it would be very afordable to start and if we like it that it could be expanded, but easy start is more important, we'd be fine with switching to a different system if we like the way of playing.

It would be good if it could be played with more players too, but strictly 2player games are ok too.

Both options of me DM-ing or us both being players and game playing itself are fine.
I'm ok with reading a lot to prepare but my SO prefers just quick intro and learning while playing.

Questions I already found have someone with at least some experience with DnD or are focused on a specific edition.

**What should two complete noobs get to start playing tabletop rpg together?**

Comment: Welcome to the stack Affaltar! Take the [tour] when you have a moment. Unfortunately, recommendation questions like this are off topic here. Fortunately, we have a [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) where you may be able to get this question answered.